# How do i move an ExtJS dashboard panel to a different column

Tags: extjs, portal, extjs6

The ExtJS 6 Portal demo starts with 3 default columns. How do I make a new panel, in a new column, start at the end of an existing "row" rather than starting a new row? You can call addNew to add a panel to the dashboard in whatever column you want. You can then drag the new panel to the top-right to make a fourth column.

For example, if you load the example:
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0/examples/classic/portal/index.html

and run this command in the console, it creates a new panel that takes up the entire width in a new row:
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].addNew('stocks', 3, 1);

I want it to show as a fourth column to the right of the "CNN Top Stories".

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution. You have to update the dashboard columnWidths array AND the individual columns columnWidth attribute. The code looks like:

```
// create the new column
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].createColumn();

// shrink column 0 by some amount to make space for the new column
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].columnWidths[0] = 0.25;
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].query('dashboard-column')[0].columnWidth = 0.25;

// shrink column 1 by some amount to make space for the new column
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].columnWidths[1] = 0.25;
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].query('dashboard-column')[1].columnWidth = 0.25;

// shrink column 2 by some amount to make space for the new column
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].columnWidths[2] = 0.25;
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].query('dashboard-column')[2].columnWidth = 0.25;

// set the new column width
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].columnWidths.push(0.25);

// add a part to the new column
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].addView({
    type: 'rss',
    feedUrl: 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/sencha'
}, (3), 1);

// update the layout so all the column sizing takes effect
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].query('dashboard-column')[0].ownerCt.updateLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you added it's look like we have the layout type [column](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Column), it's of course assumption since you didn't attach a code.

According to that the new item will fit himself to the page space and there for go to bottom.

to achieve what you have wanted add a container in the item number 3 of layout type  [Vbox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.VBox) and inside you can items one after another.

Comment: That demo uses the xtype of dashboard, which you have to configure columnWidths to get it to work. Their demo, if you run the command,  Ext.ComponentQuery.query('dashboard')[0].columnWidths, you see they only have 3 defined, which explains why you can't add a 4th column. You would have to figure out how to add a column to the dashboard and then add items. This would require resizing the columns that are already rendered to the dashboard component.

Comment: Thanks Chad. I agree. There has to be some method of adding that column, but I can't seem to find it. I tried exposing the events on the dashboard itself to see exactly what happens when you drag a panel up to the top-right, but didn't see anything. aviram83, I'll give that a shot. I would expect if I add a component at that level, that the dashboard wouldn't recognize it, but I'll try it and update the question with the results.